# Getting the spec file name into TAP file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tap, testem

we use testem to run our javascript unit tests. As output I get a TAP file, that looks similar like this

```
ok 1 PhantomJS 2.1 - ABC Directive should contain a template
---
    Log: |
        { type: 'log',
          text: '\'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.\'\n' }
...
```

lets say, the test is defined `ABCItemSpec.coffee`. Is there anyway to include this file name in the final TAP output ?

I do not understand much about the javascript/gulp setup her, so the question might be too blurry, but maybe there is a general solution (the way to setup testem, or to give the spec file as argument etc) ?